# Relation between Nginx rate limit and org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet

Tags: java, nginx, cxf, tomcat8

Let us say there are 2 web-apps (webApp-1 and webApp-2) and both are coming via Nginx reverse proxy.

Currently, both the apps have web.xml servlet config like following :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

If we notice here, `hide-service-list-page` is not configured here and [by default it is false](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html) (i.e. service listing will be visible)

Now from 2 web-apps, we configure webApp-1 for the rate limit and webApp-2 without the rate limit.

With such configuration, I observe that when we hit

webApp-1/services: I get `500 Internal Server Error from openresty`

webApp-2/services: I get the service list page for webApp-2

Is there anything that gets applied with Nginx rate-limiting that is causing `500 Internal Server Error from openresty`?

How do we ensure that webApp-1 along with rate-limiting also shows the services list page?

Comment: How does your nginx config look like?

Comment: Found the issue. There was a custom code for handling rate-limit logic which was causing failure.

@DennisKieselhorst Thanks for asking about nginx config. To cross-check and update here, I revisited nginx config and found issue which was missed last time.